# How to recognize English words via ANTLR?

Tags: antlr3, formal-languages

I would like to determirmine if a word is in a large list of keywords (vulgar and so on) and a parser should be a good solution (it should be fast as far as I know) because I need a few rules how to rewrite these words.

My question is how to add to the grammar rules like (if it is possible):

- add the asterisk after every letter in the word
- leet language
- simple rules like word + -ing, word +-ed

(There must be a tutorial for this but I was unable to find it.)

**Note:** This system will only notify admins so it doesn't have to be 100 percent accurate.

Or can you recommand me another approach that would better?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what ANTLR (or any parser generator) has got to do with determining if a word is in a (large) list of keywords. How does your input look like anyway?

Comment: Well, a word doesn't have to be in the list. The input may be: "w*o*r*d" and "word" may be in the dictionary but I would like to the parser to accept the word "w*o*r*d".

Comment: Ah, I see what you want. In that case, ANTLR is not well suited for your task: in ANTLR (or any other parser generator), you precisely define the language you want to parse up front, not "fuzzy-match" words as you go along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a task like this a regular expression or database query is probably a better bet.

Grammars work best for situations where you have very structured data that you either need to validate is syntactically correct, or that you need to parse into another structured format.

Searching for words in a corpus is more the domain of a regex.